# spring-configuration-metadata.json is not generated properly for multi-module project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, spring-boot-configuration, configurationproperties

I've created multi-module project:

- (pom) `root`

  - (jar) `libModule`
  - (jar) `appModule`, has `libModule` in dependencies

`appModule` pom has dependency:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

also it contains own `@ConfigurationProperties` class:

```java
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "service.test")
    @Component
    @Data
    public class Conf {
        String prop;
    }
```

compiling this module produces next correct `spring-configuration-metadata.json` file:

```json
{
  "groups": [
    {
      "name": "service.test",
      "type": "org.test.app.Conf",
      "sourceType": "org.test.app.Conf"
    }
  ],
  "properties": [
    {
      "name": "service.test.prop",
      "type": "java.lang.String",
      "sourceType": "org.test.app.Conf"
    }
  ],
  "hints": []
}
```

and my Idea IDE successfully highlight me this properties in `application.yml`

but also i have additional `@ConfigurationProperties` class in my `libModule`:

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "service.a")
@Setter
@Getter
public class ServiceAProperties {
    String url;
}
```

i tried to include this class into `appModule` with next code:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@ConfigurationPropertiesScan(basePackageClasses = {
        ServiceAProperties.class
})
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ConfigServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and tried different ways to include it to json but it doesn't appear there. only own module `Conf` class is used

how can i include configuration properties from other module to generate proper json including both modules' properties

if some additional info is needed please ask

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Answer to my question is - i have to generate json for libModule separately. works as it should work this way

Comment: Do you mind to explain me how you generate json for libModule ?